# How to release an object declared into a method and passed to another method?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimage, delegation

Any idea on how to release the UIImage object **picture** in this case:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    UIImage *payload = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.activeDownload];
    UIImage *picture = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    if (payload.size.width != kAppIconHeight && payload.size.height != kAppIconHeight)
    {
        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(kAppIconHeight, kAppIconHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [payload drawInRect:imageRect];
        picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    else
    {
        picture = payload;
    }

    self.activeDownload = nil;
    [payload release];

    self.imageConnection = nil;

    [delegate ThumbDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView Image:picture];
}
```

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding why your "picture" variable has an alloc init at all.  I agree with earlier answers to use autorelease, but perhaps something more like:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    UIImage *payload = [UIImage imageWithData:self.activeDownload];
    UIImage *picture = nil;
    if (payload.size.width != kAppIconHeight && payload.size.height != kAppIconHeight)
    {
        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(kAppIconHeight, kAppIconHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [payload drawInRect:imageRect];
        picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    else
    {
        picture = payload;
    }

    self.activeDownload = nil;    
    self.imageConnection = nil;

    [delegate ThumbDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView Image:picture];
}
```

Couple changes above:


   1. `UIImage *payload = [UIImage imageWithData:self.activeDownload];`.  Changed this assignment to an autoreleased object since picture may be assigned to it.  Note that the `if` clause assigns `picture` to an autoreleased object, so the `else` clause should too and now it does since payload is now an autoreleased object.

   2. `UIImage *picture = nil;` instead of `UIImage *picture = [[UIImage alloc] init];`.  I did this since the picture assignment is NEVER used, so nil is actually valid since it will definitely be assigned in either the `if` or `else` clause.

   3. No need for `[payload release]` now that `payload` is autoreleased.

Comment: there are a few errors I fixed. payload is actually "payload" I copy/paste the code and did'nt make proper changes. Now you can see changes.

Comment: i used "picture" only because i didn't know how to send UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() to the delegate and then call UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

Comment: The idea you had is right.  I modified my answer now that your Q has been changed.  To be honest, I wondered a little if the `image` variable was supposed to be `payload`.  Basically the only real change I made was to assign payload to an autoreleased image.  The answer explains why.  I think this simplifies your code, but it definitely eliminates any leaks / sigabrt.  The else was scary since `picture = payload` followed by `[payload release]` should really cause a SIGABRT if you later try to use the `picture` object.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "UIImage *payload = [UIImage imageWithData:self.activeDownload]; Changed this assignment to an autoreleased object since picture may be assigned to it."

Comment: Oh yes if not alloc/init then it's autoreleased

Comment: Thx a lot for helping! your comment helped me a lot! +1 for you!

Comment: The object, not the variable, has a retain count associated with it and may or may not be autoreleased.  The variable `payload` and `picture` are just object pointers `NSObject*`.  In this instance they are of type `UIImage*`.  I changed the code so that `payload` points to an autoreleased object (see docs on [UIImage imageWithData:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW13)).  It's possible via the `else` clause that picture is assigned to same same autoreleased object that payload is.

Comment: Guess my comment was late.  Anyhow, if this works for you, please mark as answer (unless someone else better answered your Q).  Glad I could help, please ask questions if there is something you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it autorelease

```
UIImage *picture = [[[UIImage alloc] init]autorelease];
```

Comment: Exactly. The reason is that you can't give someone (a class) another object and expect it to know that it should release it afterwards, that's the whole point of the retain count. So you send it autoreleased, which will keep the object around for long enough for the other class to be able to work with it, yet releasing it sometime in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think:
      [delegate ThumbDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView Image:[picture autorelease]];

or

```
 [delegate ThumbDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView Image:picture];
 [picture release];
```

But I see two problems in your code - leaks at picture = payload; and [payload release]; can release image, that is also indicated by the picture