# Help me understand leaks on this code:

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimage, delegation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to release an object declared into a method and passed to another method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431777/how-to-release-an-object-declared-into-a-method-and-passed-to-another-method)

Can you help me fix leaks in this code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage *payload = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.activeDownload];
    UIImage *picture = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    if (payload.size.width != kAppIconHeight && payload.size.height != kAppIconHeight)
    {
        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(kAppIconHeight, kAppIconHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [payload drawInRect:imageRect];
        picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    else
    {
        picture = payload;
    }

    self.activeDownload = nil;
    [payload release];

    self.imageConnection = nil;

    [delegate ThumbDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView Image:[picture autorelease]];
}
```

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: this is a repost [How to release an object declared into a method and passed to another method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431777/how-to-release-an-object-declared-into-a-method-and-passed-to-another-method/7432269#7432269)

Answer (score 4):

When you set `picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` in your `if` statement or `picture = payload` in your `else` statement, you are loosing the pointer to the previously allocated UIImage you assigned in `picture` in the first lines, but you never released it.

You shouldn't alloc+init a new UIImage for `picture`, as you never use it and assign a new value to this variable later... but never used and released the previously allocated one.

Comment: but when doing "picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();" is not saving it into the picture instance I declared on line 2 (UIImage *picture = [[UIImage alloc] init];) ?

Comment: Of course not. That's like if you were doing `int x = 5` and some lines later `x = 12`. Of course your value 5 is then lost forever. here you assign to your `picture` variable an objet that already exists in memory. The object you previously allocated using `alloc+init` and previously stored in `picture` is obviously a completely different (and useless, and leaked) one.

Answer (score 0):

1. `UIImage *picture = [[UIImage alloc] init];` and `picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`
   You should not initialize `picture` at the beginning of the code. `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` returns a already initialized `UIImage` (autoreleased).
2. `UIImage *payload = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.activeDownload];`, `picture = payload;`, `[payload release];`.
   You should use `[payload autorelease]` instead, otherwise you're releasing the image without ever using it.
3. `[delegate ThumbDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView Image:[picture autorelease]];`
   You should remove `[picture autorelease]` and just use `picture`.

   ```
   -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
       UIImage *payload = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.activeDownload];
       UIImage *picture;
       if (payload.size.width != kAppIconHeight && payload.size.height != kAppIconHeight)
       {
           CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(kAppIconHeight, kAppIconHeight);
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
           CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
           [payload drawInRect:imageRect];
           picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
       }
       else
       {
           picture = payload;
       }
       [payload autorelease];
       self.activeDownload = nil;

       self.imageConnection = nil;

       [delegate ThumbDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView Image:picture];
   }
   ```